# No permission to use commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I put a command or a chat in Minecraft it says I have no permission and if you should know I have a mac. I have tried to switch multiplayer settings, which still did not work. As well as tried searching on Youtube.

Comment: Are you playing in singleplayer or on a server?

Comment: Possible duplicaate of [How to turn cheats on or off](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277542/how-to-turn-cheats-on-or-off)

Answer (score 5):

If you're playing in single player, you might not have "cheats" allowed. To allow them, pause the game and select the option "Open to LAN". In this menu, select he option that says "Allow Cheats". This will only last until you close the LAN server.

If you're playing on a server, you might not have the privilege to use commands. If this is the case, you will need to talk to the server owners about their rules.

Comment: The only other way is to edit the level.dat file and set AllowCheats to 1. The level.dat is compressed, you can use unzip to expand it. Then you can either use a binary(hex) editor, or one of the many NBT editors available online. Just be sure to re-pack it after you make changes or it wont work. Also, be sure to not change the size of the level.dat or disturb any other values. I personally prefer to just hexedit it. And, as always MAKE A BACKUP FIRST.